# Convert Docx to Pdf not working in server machine

Tags: java, batch-file, pdf, cmd

In my project, I have to convert the docx to pdf. To convert the docx to pdf i run the bat file using processbuilder object. It's working in my local environment, but not working in server machine and the same time it's not throwing any exception. Below is my code.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try{

        String path = "C:\\selva\\";
        String arg1 = "C:\\kumar\\a.docm";
        String command = "cmd.exe /c start " + path + "runner.bat "+arg1;



        String runCommand=path + "runner.bat";


        ProcessBuilder pb = null;

        pb = new ProcessBuilder(runCommand, arg1);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        pb.start();


         response.sendRedirect("/GENERATEPDFFROMDOCX/genPDF.jsp");  
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Runner.bat

```
echo %1
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\winword.exe" /mExportToPDFext %1>ONE.TXT

Local Machine Log:
C:\Users\Selva\Desktop\eclipse>echo C:\kumar\a.docm 
C:\kumar\a.docm

C:\Users\Selva\Desktop\eclipse>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\winword.exe" /mExportToPDFext C:\kumar\a.docm 1>ONE.TXT 

Error Code is 0
Process Finished
Server Log:
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0>echo C:\kumar\a.docm 
C:\kumar\CarLoanAgreement.docm

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\winword.exe" /mExportToPDFext C:\kumar\a.docm 1>ONE.TXT 
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Error Code is 1
Process Finished
```

What's wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

in your code you're hardcoding some paths to some software.

Most probable reasons why it's not working on server are:

- the server uses different type of OS
- the paths are not present on the
  server
- the software that converts the document is not installed
- the
  user running the web application on server does not have permissions
  to execute anything